# I am writing a program to ask the user to enter the name of a person, and a coin value (as an integer) using just arrays

Tags: java

The program is recommended for the user to input at least 10 such data using setters and getters, however i am getting error message on "String cannot be converted to String[]".

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter at least 10 records to test the program");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");
    changeC.setName(keyboard.next());
    System.out.println("Please enter the coin value for the person: ");
    changeC.setChangeAmount(keyboard.nextDouble());
    System.out.println("Do you have more person to enter (Y/N): ");
    String answer = keyboard.next();
    if(prompt = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
        break;
    }                
}
```

```
private String[] name;
    private double[] changeAmount;
   
    public void setName(String[] name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String[] getName() {
        return name;
    }
      
       
    /**
     * @return the changeAmount
     */
    public double[] getChangeAmount() {
        return changeAmount;
    }

    /**
     * @param changeAmount the changeAmount to set
     */
    public void setChangeAmount(double[] changeAmount) {
        this.changeAmount = changeAmount;
    }
```

Comment: the error says it all. you can't do something like String[] array = "test"; -> "test" can be an element of an array, but it isn't an array. assign it to a specific index of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare two arrays (a String and a double one) assigning the values you get from input directly to the array index using the i variable, then at the end you assign those arrays to the changeC object.

EDIT:
the arrays assignments must be done at the same time as you assign the inputs now

Comment: why would this be a good approach? if there's a problem in reading the 8th name, the changeC wouldn't contain any info at all

Comment: actually you're right, maybe the assignment will have to be done every time the user inputs some data